# difficulties in using ranges with dynamic polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, boost-range

Suppose the following

```
// interface that provides a range of ints
struct C
{
    virtual RangeOfInts foreach() const = 0;
};

struct B
{
    void g(const C& c_) {
        for (int i : c_.foreach()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
};

struct A
{
    struct C1 : public C
    {
        // implementation of C with A specific info, for example
        RangeOfInts foreach() const override {
            return v | boost::adaptors::transformed([](int i){return i*2;});
        }
        std::vector<int> v;
    };

    void f() {
        b.g(c1);
    }

    B b;
    C1 c1;
};
```

I'd usually use `auto` when dealing with range types, but clearly that won't work for dynamic polymorphism.

Is there an easy way to define the type `RangeOfInts`? Perhaps `boost::any_range`?

Or any suggestions on how I can improve the design here?

Comment: From name, I would do `virtual void foreach(std::function<void(int)>) = 0;`.

Comment: range-v3 has `any_view<T>` for that.